# Copy/Clone Hierarchical data in SQL Server with Identity column

Tags: sql-server, tree, parent-child, identity, hierarchical-data

I have data in hierarchical/Tree/Parent Child form.

Here is a screenshot of the data:

[image]

The requirement is to write a query that copies or clones the data based on `Project_Id`.

The resultant data should look like this:

[image]

The queries I know is like:

```
INSERT INTO Task_Table 
AS 
    SELECT cols  
    FROM Task 
    WHERE Project_Id = 10.
```

But the issue I am experiencing is that the Task_Id (primary key) is Identity column.

Comment: What is the difference between first and second pictures?

Comment: First picture is the source data, and the second one includes source and copied/cloned data